# Difference between Promise and RxJS

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to understand the following text but finding it difficult because I haven't worked with Promise and planning to start RxJS with Angular:

**"The drawback of using Promises is that they’re unable to handle data sources that produce more than one value, like mouse movements or sequences of bytes in a file stream"**

In the example

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // the function is executed automatically when the promise is constructed
  setTimeout(() => resolve("done"), 1000);
});
```

Does it mean that the mouse events cannot be called inside this function? What exactly is the meaning of more than one value means? An array?

Comment: it means when a promise is settled it is settled

Comment: I mean, no one would ever handle (mouse) event by `Promise`, register the event handler, don't make simple things complicated.

Comment: for example, the `document.onmouse***` events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promise object represents a future result of a single asynchronous operation; once that operation is completed, promise either fulfills or is rejected. Promises cannot be used and are not designed to represent the results of repeated asynchronous operations.

Promises are not suitable for use with sources of multiple asynchronous events such as `click` event in the browser, `setInterval()` or a data event on a NodeJS stream. As user events can happen multiple times, in this case, you will use an event handler, that can execute multiple times, instead of a promise because single promise cannot execute multiple times, once its settled, its done.